# How can I dynamically change a Flickable's contentHeight?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a simple Flickable with a Grid in it. Using the scroll wheel, I append objects to the grid. What I'm trying to do is alter the Flickable's contentHeight once the Grid elements exceed the default contentHeight.

Here is my code:

```
Flickable {
    property real flickHeight: Screen.height * 2
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    contentWidth: Screen.width
    contentHeight: flickHeight

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: {
            gridModel.append({ _color: "black" })
            var cheight = (gridModel.count * 180 + gridModel.count * 2)
            if(cheight > parent.flickHeight) {
                parent.flickHeight = cheight
            }
            console.log("Flickable.flickHeight: " + parent.flickHeight) // Prints qml: Flickable.flickHeight: undefined
        }
    } // MouseArea

    Grid {
        ListModel {
            id: gridModel
            ListElement { _color: "red" }
            ListElement { _color: "blue" }
            ListElement { _color: "green" }
            ListElement { _color: "darkred" }
            ListElement { _color: "darkblue" }
            ListElement { _color: "darkgreen" }
        } // ListModel

        id: grid
        columns: 2
        spacing: 2

        Repeater {
            model: gridModel
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 180
                height: 180
                color: _color
            } // Delegate
        } // Repeater
    } // Grid
} // Flickable
```

Everything works great except for when I'm trying to alter the height of the contentHeight. The onWheel function prints out "qml: Flickable.flickHeight: undefined". Am I not using properties correctly? Why am I getting "undefined"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your `MouseArea` is not a direct child of `Flickable`, but rather of `Flickable.contentItem`. So you cannot use `parent` in this context because it references different element. A quick solution is to use ids:

```
Flickable {
    id: flickable

    ...

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWheel: {
            ...
            console.log("Flickable.flickHeight: " + flickable.flickHeight)
        }
    } // MouseArea

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you this solves my issue :) May I ask what the parent actually is in this case? Also I never id'd my Flickable because I read somewhere that due to an implementation detail you should only refer to it as a parent. I must have misunderstood that. Thanks again!

Comment: I've mentioned that in the answer. The actual parent is content item (`Flickable.contentItem`). Flickable itself is more like a view port, while the contain item moves behind it.